# Function works ramdonly, overwriting memory, double free, corruption (!prev)

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

I learning C programing and I think I do well  but this I have been trying for hours and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I made a funtion to print an array and it works fine but just the first time, later on print weird character o don't work, with the gdb see that works fine but when I call printArray a second time the funtion integerToString dosen't works the second time. Honestly I don't know how to fix it, I asking for a few help please ;-; I'm asking anything you comment

The folowing code is a minimum reproducible example but the problem I think is just in the seeArray function and integerToString function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

//Dependecy
int randomInRange(int lower, int upper){
    return (random() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
}

//Dependecy
int countDigits(int num, int * numSize){
    *numSize = 0;
    do{
            (* numSize)++;
            num /= 10;
    }while(num != 0);

    return 0;
}

//Here is where things gets broke!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
int integerToString(int num, char** strNum, int* strNumSize){
    countDigits(num, strNumSize);
    *strNum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (*strNumSize));
    if(*strNum == 0x0){
            fprintf(stderr, "No enough memory for convert interger to string");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int i = (*strNumSize-1); i > -1; i--){
            *( (*strNum) + i ) = num%10 + '0';
            num /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
//Dependecy
int initArray(int** array, int size){
    if(size<1){
            fprintf(stderr, "The array\'s size most be minimun one");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    if(*array == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn\'t reserve memory for array");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) *((*array)+i) == 0;
    return 0;
}

//Here is where things gets broke!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
int seeArray(int* array, int size, char** arrayPhotography, int* arrayPhotographySize){
    int dataSize = 0;
    char* data = 0x0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            integerToString(*(array+i), &data, &dataSize);

            *arrayPhotographySize += sizeof(char) * ( 2 + dataSize );
            if(*arrayPhotography == 0x0){
                    *arrayPhotography = (char *) malloc(*arrayPhotographySize);
            }else{
                    *arrayPhotography = (char *) realloc(*arrayPhotography,*arrayPhotographySize);
            }
            if(*arrayPhotography == 0x0){
                    fprintf(stderr,"Not enoug memory for array\'s photography");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            strcat(*arrayPhotography, "[");
            strcat(*arrayPhotography, data);
            strcat(*arrayPhotography, "]");

            free(data);
            data = 0x0;
    }

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
//Dependecy
int printArray(int* array, int size){
    int arrayPhotographySize = 0;
    char* arrayPhotography = 0x0;
    if(seeArray(array, size, &arrayPhotography, &arrayPhotographySize)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Fuction printArray");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Array:%s\n", arrayPhotography);
    free(arrayPhotography);
    return 0;
}
//Here is where things gets broke!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arraySize = randomInRange(1, 15);
    int* array = 0x0;
    initArray(&array, arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printArray(array, arraySize);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

This are an image of how works randomly (I think so)

[image]

Comment: In initArray `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) *((*array)+i) == 0;` it should be `=` not `==`

Comment: I'm stupid thanks ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It appears that in your `initArray` function, in the final for loop you write `==` instead of `=` to zero-fill the array. On a side note, there exists a function `calloc` in the `<stdlib.h>` header which will automatically zero-fill a dynamically allocated array for you, which is handy for avoiding simple mistakes like this.
2. In your `integerToString` function, you only `malloc` enough space to hold the number of digits in the string. This is error-prone code however because most string operations in C (including `strcat`) require strings to be terminated by a null character. Allocate space for one extra character and then ensure the final character is 0.